# Tornado IOStream.read_until_close does not work properly

Tags: python, networking, asynchronous, tornado

### Code

Use Tornado IOStream.read_until_close for reading http response.

```
from tornado import ioloop
from tornado import iostream
import socket    

class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, domen, uri):
        self.uri = uri
        self.domen = domen

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
        self.stream = iostream.IOStream(s)

    def open(self):
        self.stream.connect((self.domen, 80), self.send_request)

    def on_chunk_read(self, chunk):
        print "chunk\n", chunk

    def on_close(self, res):
        print "res\n", res
        self.stream.close()
        ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()

    def send_request(self):
        self.stream.write(
            "GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n" % (self.uri,  self.domen))
        self.stream.read_until_close(self.on_close, self.on_chunk_read)

client = Client("www.google.com", "/")
client.open()

ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

### Output

```
res
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.ru/
...
<HTML>
...
</HTML>
```

### Documentation [tornado.iostream](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/iostream.html#tornado.iostream.IOStream.read_until_close)

```
read_until_close(callback, streaming_callback=None)
Reads all data from the socket until it is closed.

If a streaming_callback is given, it will be called with chunks of data as they 
become  available, and the argument to the final callback will be empty.

Subject to max_buffer_size limit from IOStream constructor if a 
streaming_callback is not used.
```

### Сonclusion

Code 'print "chunk\n", chunk' not called.
Called callback, but streaming_callback not called.

It is bug?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not a bug, depending on the length of stream, send to you as one or chunks.

```
def on_chunk_read(self, chunk):
    print "chunk\n", len(chunk)

def on_close(self, res):
    print "res\n", len(res)
    self.stream.close()
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
```

1.one, redirect, short content with only headers.

```
client = Client("www.google.com", "/")
```

output

```
res
1279
```

2.chunks,

```
client = Client("www.google.ru", "/")

chunk
4837
chunk
1418
chunk
1418
chunk
1418
...
chunk
1418
res
1093
```